# Why can an ActionListener access private variables of the class?

Tags: java, variables, actionlistener

Hi I'm new to Java and I have following questions (I already searched the forum but I don't understand it yet):

Why is it possible to access private class variables from the actionlistener like that:

```
public class Test{
private int x;

   Test(){
     init();
   }

....

   public void init(){

....
   Button button_1 = new Button("buttonTest");
        button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                x++;
            }
        });

   }

}
```

And why can't I put the previous code snipped (creating button + actionlistener) into the constuctor without errors ("x cannot be resolved") ?

Greetings

Comment: We have no idea, what is your previous code snippet.

Comment: It shouldn´t make a difference if the code is in your constructor or in a seperate method, there shouldn´t be any compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing `x++;` try using `Test.this.x++;`

The problem is you are trying to access data member from anonymous inner class. If you write `x++;` then it'll refer to local variable within `actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)` method which is not present. So to refer to the data member of class you have to use `this` but since you are using anonymous inner class you have to tell class name also, so it becomes `Test.this.x++;`.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    Test.this.x++;
                }
```

Comment: Thank you :) - And can you explain that to me ?

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it possible to access private class variables from the actionlistener like that:

Your `actionListener` class is inside your `Test` class. Therefore the `actionListener` accesses the `private` atribute form inside the class, so privte works fine. If you want to prevent that create a seperate file for your `actionListener`